# Amazon SDK for Php SNS Publish Error 500

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am getting an error 500 when trying to do a SNS publish using the Amazon AWS SDK for PHP. If I run `PHP sendPush.php` in terminal it works perfectly fine but if I go to the URL in chrome I get an error 500.

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

$arn = "<my arn endpoint here>";
$message = 'test1';

$provider = CredentialProvider::env();

$client = SnsClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'credentials' => $provider,
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'us-east-1'
));

$message_atr =  array(
        'String' => array(
            'DataType' => 'String',
            'StringValue' => $message
        )
    );

$publish_message = array('TargetArn' => $arn,'Message' => $message,'MessageAttributes'=> $message_atr);

$client->publish($publish_message);


?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs. I'd guess the path location is different on your web execution.

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: it was an issue with my credentials, I had the .aws folder in the wrong location

Answer (score 0):

I had the .aws folder in the wrong location, it works now.